# proxies+verify kwargs break HTTP/2 in httpx

Tags: python, ssl, proxy, httpx

Versions: httpx 0.23.3 and httpcore 0.16.3.

```
import httpx

s=httpx.Client(
    http2=True, proxies='http://127.0.0.1:9000', verify=False
)
r=s.get('https://in.indeed.com')
print(r.http_version)
```

Commenting out proxies/verify gives HTTP/2. The proxy is regular mitmproxy.

I've found this: https://github.com/encode/httpx/issues/873, but it was allegedly fixed in 2020. I've briefly viewed the respective code in httpx, and see http2 is passed everywhere, so probably it's somewhere deeper.

Comment: *"I've found this: ...."* - Please provide the full context of your question instead of just linking to some external site which one first need to read in order to understand what your question is about.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich. No big context, the code explains it hopefully. Without 2 kwargs the connection is HTTP/2, with them it's 1.1 despite http2=True. Which is not how it's meant to be? But I'll move the link to the end of the post, it will be more logical, I agree.

Comment: Have you checked what happens if you comment out only one? Also, which version of mitmproxy you are using and have you analyzed if there is no TLS interception done for the target (see https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/howto-ignoredomains/).

Comment: Yeah, with only verify it gives HTTP/2, with only proxies it gives ssl Exception about certificate verification failure. mitmproxy 9.0.1, and when I try curl (curl -kx 127.0.0.1:9000), it serves HTTP/2. That's why I've concluded it's something about httpx/httpcore. Without interception (no verify and no proxies) it serves HTTP/2, that's why I've brought up that link:) I've played with creating ssl contexts in different ways, essentially it boils down to the same: if there's verify and proxies, it doesn't work.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, I've found something to make it work, but I will still wait for the consideration by Tom Christie or maintainers…

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know what would be the proper way, but I've changed the line to set alpn_protocols to ["h2"] in httpcore in TunnelHTTPConnection/handle_request() to force it unconditionally, and it now gives me HTTP/2.